# Complete x86/x64 JIT Assembler for C Language

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, jit

Do you know something just like [this](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/), but embeddable in a C program?

Comment: His link is for a JIT for C++; he wants one for C.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, title updated.
Yep, C, not C++.

Comment: Why do you want it?  There seems to be no advantage over simply writing an assembly module.

Comment: I'm working on a small language which must be written in C. This kind of library would help me 1) easily translate IR to ASM, and finally to binary, without having to read thousands of pages of specs from Intel; 2) easily turn it into a "scripting" language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some options:

- [LibJIT](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/)
- [GNU Lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)
- The LLVM C bindings
- Compiling modules with a C compiler and `dlopen`ing them - it works everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something tiny and relatively simple to embed in your application, there is also:

- [TCC - Tiny C Compiler](https://bellard.org/tcc/).

It's old but damn it's tiny & fast, and it still runs perfectly on RedHad 8.6.

Comment: For this question, the important part is that it's already factored into `libtcc` so you can use it as a library without needing to fork/exec the `tcc` executable.  IDK if it can JIT into memory, though, or if you'd just have to use it to make a shared library you can dlopen.  Also, of course the machine-code it produces is *not* optimized, it's aiming to compile fast, one statement at a time, in one pass.  So if you're looking for JIT once, run many times, LLVM is a much better bet.

Comment: In fact, we use it through libtcc as you suggest. And yes it can JIT into memory, but we encountered some trouble with SELinux on some machine. I find it highly reliable as our application stay about ~90% of execution time in the jitted code. The instruction overhead is real but it was way more simple for us than LLVM. I would have been happy to exercice a bit with LLVM but budget is budget...

Comment: A fast but non-optimizing JIT that makes slow machine code will spend a large fraction of the total time in the JITted code.  That's not a good thing unless the code changes often so each JIT result is only executed a few times.  But sure, simple and good-enough can be fine for some use-cases.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to details that we have a lot of code eviction and recompilation.